# Optimizing the Oracle group on queries in very large data of table

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization

**I have a query I would like to optimize. This is the query:**

```
SELECT "c"."NETSW_ACQEREF" AS "BANK",
       count("c"."NETSW_ACQEREF") AS "QTY",
       sum("c"."TRAN_AMNT") / 100 AS "AMOUNT",
       count(distinct "c"."TERM_ID") as "terminals"
  FROM "CSCLWH"."CLWH_COMMON_DATA" "c"
 WHERE ("c"."TRAN_DATE" between 20201101 AND 20201111)
   AND ("TRAN_TYPE" IN
       ('00', '01', '10', '12', '19', '20', '26', '29', '50', '51', '52'))
   AND ("RESP_CODE" IN ('0', '00', '000', '400'))
   AND ("MTI" IN ('1100', '1200', '1240', '1400', '1420'))
 GROUP BY "c"."NETSW_ACQEREF"
 ORDER BY "BANK"
```

These are the explain plan results with huge cost:

```
Cost 5102095 Time 00:03:20
```

it has date 3 million rows I've created group by index but it less useful. Can you please show me a way to get the cost down?

Comment: Why are you comparing transaction date to NUMBERS (20201101 and 20201111)? Is the transaction date column in NUMBER data type? That may be a significant issue. Even if you have an index on that column, if the data type is wrong, the index won't help much - even if it would otherwise help a lot (if the data type was DATE).

Answer (score 1):

The aggregation operations `COUNT` and `SUM` can't be optimized much, and also there is no `HAVING` clause, so your best bet here would probably be to add a multi-column index covering the entire `WHERE` clause:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx ON "CSCLWH"."CLWH_COMMON_DATA" (TRAN_DATE, TRAN_TYPE, RESP_CODE, MTI);
```

This index, if used, would at least allow Oracle to discard many records not matching the where filter.  The exact order of the columns used in the index would depend on the cardinality of the data in each column.  Typically, you want to put columns first which are more restrictive, placing less restrictive columns last.

Comment: thanks I will be create but I want optimize this query How to optimize it?

Comment: Other than adding the above index, there isn't much you can do.  Adding the index _is_ optimizing the query.

Comment: For example can you give me some examples . I have created index for single columns actually it was useless

Comment: `can you give me some examples` ... I thought my answer _was_ an example.  If you can't invest a few moments of your time to at least try my answer, I don't know what else I can do here...

Comment: The first question to ask the OP should be: "How many rows are in the table in total, and how many pass the WHERE filter". I have a strong suspicion that many rows do; if so, then indexing won't help. More likely, aggregation and sorting take the bulk of the time. Reading from the table is O(n) (n = cardinality); grouping and sorting are O(n log n), and "n" appears to be just big enough to make grouping and sorting the likely bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

I can see two potential sources of slowness in your query. You can run a couple of tests to see which is worse. There is an easy way to fix one of them; I don't think you can do much about the other.

You don't only have the `group by` aggregation at the overall query level; you also have a count(**distinct** {something}). That count **distinct** is a nested aggregation which is expensive. What happens if you remove the word "distinct" there? Meaning, how does the execution time change? (Of course, that will not give you the result you need; but it will tell you HOW EXPENSIVE the "distinct" is.)

Unfortunately, if THAT is the biggest bottleneck, there is nothing you can do about it.

The other source of slowness is the ORDER BY clause at the end of the query. A bit of background: there are essentially two ways to SORT BY. One is to order the expressions you "group by"; the other is to hash them. In the old days, Oracle used "sort" group by - which is expensive. As a side effect, results were ordered by the GROUP BY expressions even without an explicit ORDER BY clause; that is how developers acquired very poor habits.

At some point Oracle "learned" that "hash" group by is faster. However, they fell into a trap: when you have GROUP BY followed by ORDER BY the same expressions, Oracle thought (incorrectly for most cases) that they can save time by doing both in one shot by simply using the old "sort" group by. This is very wasteful when 3 million rows in the input result perhaps in 300 groups. Better to hash group by for the 3 million rows, and then have the (additional, but trivial) step of ordering 300 output rows. Why Oracle is so dumb as not to see this, I don't know - it's just how it is.

This problem, though, has a very simple solution. You can force hash group by with the `use_hash_aggregation` hint. (First, you can simply remove the ORDER BY clause from your query to see if that's the problem; if you see no improvement, then adding the hint about hash aggregation will not help.)

I have no idea which of the two problems I described is worse. And if it's the "sort group by" (the only one you can do something about), don't expect miracles. You may see the execution time drop from 3 minutes and 20 seconds to 2 minutes or 2 minutes and 30 seconds or whatnot; not an order of magnitude of improvement.

Comment: Consider also suggesting placing an index on `TRAN_DATE`, as it is likely that the table covers many dates, while the query in question targets only two of those dates.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - More importantly, from the way the query is written it seems the "dates" are stored as numbers. If so, even with an index, the optimizer will draw wrong conclusions. In any case - even without an index, the time to read everything from the table grows only linearly with cardinality, while aggregation and sorting are worse than that. I would start with those, although indeed fixing the issues about `tran_date` may prove important too.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - it seems to me the query targets 11 days, from 1 Nov. to 11 Nov. It's still possible an index could help, especially if the data type was DATE.

Comment: Tran_date is varchar2(8)  and I use group by in the query so create simple, single(create index IDX1 CLWH_COMMON_DATA(tran_date)) indexs it is useless Maybe another ways have Hence this query uses for report everyday everymonth or inside which days for example 01.11.2020 and 12.11.2020 . I want optimize with sub query but I can't do it

Comment: @Ma'rufJavliyev - OK, then (1) why are you comparing the dates to numbers in your query, and not to strings? (2) Much more importantly - can you change the data type in your real-life table? Indexing as strings for things that are supposed to be dates will be useless. (3) Did you try what I suggested, and if you did, what did you learn from it? Namely: run the query without the final ORDER BY. Does it run faster? Run the query with count(terminals) instead of count(distinct terminals). Does it run faster?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if two levels of aggregation with appropriate indexes would help:

```
SELECT bank, SUM(qty) as qty, SUM(amount) as amount,
       count(*) as terminals
FROM (SELECT "c"."NETSW_ACQEREF" AS bank, "c"."TERM_ID",
             count(*) AS qty,
             sum("c"."TRAN_AMNT") / 100 AS "AMOUNT",
      FROM "CSCLWH"."CLWH_COMMON_DATA" "c"
      WHERE "c"."TRAN_DATE" between 20201101 AND 20201111 AND
            "TRAN_TYPE" IN ('00', '01', '10', '12', '19', '20', '26', '29', '50', '51', '52') AND
            "RESP_CODE" IN ('0', '00', '000', '400') AND
            "MTI" IN ('1100', '1200', '1240', '1400', '1420')
      GROUP BY "c"."NETSW_ACQEREF", "c"."TERM_ID"
     ) c
GROUP BY bank
ORDER BY BANK;
```

This assumes that `tran_type`, `resp_code`, and `MTI` are all strings.  If they are numbers, then change the comparisons to use numbers.

Then you want an index for the `WHERE` clause.  It is quite unclear what the best possibilities are, but something like `(tran_date, mti, tran_type, resp_code)` -- these should be most selective first.